# Mouse gets stuck in "down" mode on remote disconnect

Tags: windows, mouse

So, we have a problem where, when using remoting software like GoToMeeting or VNC, if the mouse is held down on the remote end and then the connection is suddenly lost, the mouse stays in "stuck down" mode until clicked on the local machine. For our use case, this could be a safety hazard, and so far I've been unsuccessful in finding remoting software that doesn't behave like that.

I know it's a long shot to expect anyone to know of software that *doesn't* do that, but if anyone has any ideas about workarounds, I'm all ears! For example, is there a setting/utility that would "cut off" a mousedown after some short period of time or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note sure of your setup but I use [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/) and I could not reproduce this. Going from a Win7 -> Win7, XP -> Win7 and Win7 -> XP.

Comment: This seemed to work, albeit after a delay while the software realized it was being disconnected. It'll take more testing, but it's better than anything I've tried, so I'll go ahead and accept.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [Team Viewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/) for a long time on different versions of Windows and never faced this kind of problem. You may give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this out, using a test app that polls for mousedown, and unfortunately the mouse remains down if it was down at the time of unexpected disconnection.